# Cannot move an app to the SD card

Tags: android, permissions, sd-card

I am not able to move my own application to the SD card.

My corresponding parts of manifest are as below (I am pasting also what permissions it needs).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="6"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

I believe I followed guidelines described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html (compatibility and pemissions). However, during installation (from SDK but also from Android Market) applications lands on internal storage, and I can't move it using "Manage Applications".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    package="your.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
...
...
```

Comment: OCH! I put it into application, not manifest! Thanks! Gonna try in few hours!

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `android:installLocation="auto"` in your `<manifest>` tag

Comment: `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` works as well, but simply tells Android to prefer external storage, even if the user has their preference set to internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Backwards Compatibility section of the App Install Location docs,

> Existing applications that were built prior to API Level 8 will always
>   install on the internal storage and cannot be moved to the external
>   storage (even on devices with API Level 8).

However, you can still take advantage of the install location feature by setting your build target to API level 8 (or higher).

To do so, right click on your project, then go to Properties > Android. Select API level 8 (Android 2.2) or higher from the list.

Comment: from same page:
Include the android:installLocation attribute with a value of "auto" or "preferExternal" in the <manifest> element.
Leave your android:minSdkVersion attribute as is (something less than "8") and be certain that your application code uses only APIs compatible with that level.
In order to compile your application, change your build target to API Level 8. This is necessary because older Android libraries don't understand the android:installLocation attribute and will not compile your application when it's present.

Comment: And I didnt mention that I use eclipse.

Comment: You also didn't mention that you _don't_ use eclipse, which is the far more common method of developing Android applications. I didn't include the minSDK and installLocation information in my answer, as you already had those in the XML you posted.

Comment: You wrote "build target to API level 8 (or higher)" - it is not equal with "android:targetSdkVersion="9" /> " which I posted above?

Comment: No. You build target can be different from the targetSdkVersion. The build target is what your code is actually validated against. The targetSdkVersion is used by the Google Play store and actual android device.

Comment: Your answer in the last comment is quite confusing for me. I googled a bit, and I found for example this one: http://www.coderanch.com/t/538546/Android/Mobile/minSDKVersion-vs-Build-Target - one of the answers suggest  that build target is used only by eclipse. What its related with my question then? Please share some source more descriptive - for now I have impression that "build target" which is set in eclipse is used only in eclipse for validation the build.

Comment: Yes, it is only used by eclipse. I confused myself when answering your question, sorry.